# aws backup s3 Resource ARN is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to backup my s3 bucket on aws. It should be pretty straightforward but for some reason i get 'Resource ARN is not valid' error for the bucket that im trying to backup. Versioning is enabled , permissions are there. Has anybody encountered something similar? Or is it a bug?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the ARN please?

Comment: I added a pic of it

Comment: are you sure your bucket exists, are you sure your session is not expired?

Comment: yes. I even tried it on 2 different accounts to make sure its not a permission issue

Comment: You r not experiencing the same?

Comment: I had to add a trailing slash my similar sitch. i.e. arn:aws:s3:::local-vagrant/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the documentation in AWS .

Another thing to check for  is to verify that the IAM permissions for the user or role that you're using to back up the S3 bucket are correctly configured.
The user or role should have the necessary permissions to access and read the S3 bucket.

Comment: It was s3 bucket permission. Default aws backup role or even more broad role from IAM list dont have S3 in there (have to add it manually). Invalid ARN is not a very helpful message. I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: yeah i know most of the  issues that I experienced around aws revolve around permissions

Comment: Its accepted because it got me to how to fix the problem. Which is add permissions to the IAM role.

Comment: i m not sure what is your problem if the solution or part of it  helped some one get things done

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot. For anyone else looking, the AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole, which is created by AWS, needs to be modified. You need to add these policies to it:

- AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup
- AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForRestores
- AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForS3Backup (add)
- AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForS3Restore (add)

This allows you to create a backup of S3 with the IAM Default role selected.

Answer (score 3):

The way to fix this is:

1. Go to Identity and Access Management (IAM) console: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home
2. Select "Roles" from the menu on the left side
3. Search for `AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole`
4. Click on it => Add Permissions (in the right side) => Attach policies
5. Search for `AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForS3Backup` => select it
6. Search for `AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForS3Restore` => select
7. "Add permissions"

Now if you go back to Backup you should be able to create an On-Demand Backup using the `Default role` option.